# Using the current time in an IF statement

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code

```
        Dim time As Date
    Dim currentHour As Integer
    Dim currentMinute As Integer

    time = DateTime.Now
    currentHour = time.Hour
    currentMinute = time.Minute

    If currentHour > 10 AndAlso currentMinute > 8 Then
        Response.Redirect("holdingpage.aspx")

    Else
        'do nothing
    End If
```

BAsically I want to redirect to another page if the current time is after 10.08am but nothing happens.

Comment: Better look at the redirect part (or at the current time on your computer), because this code is fine.

Comment: I thought it was I will re-check my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your code will fail if it is 11:00.

Use either

```
If currentHour > 10 OrElse (currentHour = 10 AndAlso currentMinute > 8) Then
```

Or even better

```
If Date.Now.TimeOfDay > New TimeSpan(10, 8, 0) Then
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorted it, I basically added in = as its 10.30 in the UK so it failed with out the equals.

Code is now

```
        Dim time As Date
    Dim currentHour As Integer
    Dim currentMinute As Integer

    time = DateTime.Now
    currentHour = time.Hour
    currentMinute = time.Minute

    If currentHour >= 10 And currentMinute >= 8 Then
        Response.Redirect("HoldingPage.aspx")

    Else
        'do nothing
    End If
```

Comment: So when it's 11:00, it's clearly after 10:08, but *only the first* condition evalutes to `true`, since `currentMinute` is not greater or equal `8`, so it still doesn't work.